# IIS7.5 Application Pool, process identity and environment

Tags: .net, git, iis

I have web application that have to access local resources, files/folders, to be able to do git clone/pull/push. I've created a separate Application Pool with Process Identity == my own account (Administrator of machine).

But, if I do:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

The return value:

```
"C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Local"
```

so, it looks like system profile is still used. `git clone` and other git operations hangs up, seems like fail to find .ssh keys etc.

The interesting thing, that it worked fine before Windows SP1 update (at least I blame update, since nothing more changed on machine).

Comment: Did you check in debugger what is Thread.CurrentPrincipal when that line runs?

Comment: Yes and it returns "my" account, correctly.

Comment: it returns:     [System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity]: {System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity}
    AuthenticationType: "Forms"
    IsAuthenticated: true
    Name: "admin"

Comment: Should not there be windows identity?

Comment: I think you right.. It might be some issue here. At least some info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If already not having it, try setting:

```
<identity impersonate="false"/>
```

in web.config

**EDIT**

I was wrong, you need to have your app pool identity with access to local folder here:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

**EDIT 2**

I have found solution. To run application AS you, you need to turn on impersonation after all (app pool setting does not apply on my IIS7.5), but AS A SPECIFIC USER. So, to enable this, you need to turn impersonation on in web.config AND specify user:

```
    <identity impersonate="true" password="o1j2813n" userName="obrad" />
```

You can also set this through inetmgr:
[image: ASP.NET Impersonation Settings screenshot]

Either way, after setting this,

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

gives:

```
C:\Users\obrad\AppData\Local
```

**Another update:**

I have been searching for a way to do the same without putting my password in web.config, and can confirm that I get local user folder also when basic impersonation is on

```
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
```

But under condition that application connects (under app settings -> Connect as...) as me:

[image: app settings screenshot]

Comment: Can you see what is current principal when not impersonating? It should be app pool identity...

Comment: Well that is the problem, I just have to check what needs to be done for this to work under app pool identity.

Comment: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
{System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity}
    AuthenticationType: "NTLM"
    Groups: {System.Security.Principal.IdentityReferenceCollection}
    ImpersonationLevel: None
    IsAnonymous: false
    IsAuthenticated: true
    IsGuest: false
    IsSystem: false
    Name: "seekey-note\\alexander.beletsky"
    Owner: {S-1-5-32-544}
    Token: 1444
    User: {S-1-5-21-3002142266-3819629678-4064189035-1000}

Comment: ImpersonationLevel: None - might it cause problem?

Comment: I don't think so, because impersonation is for currently logged in user, you don't need that, you want to run under APP POOL identity, that is unimpersonated. I'm without idea...

Comment: I had found solution which works for me. Updated my answer now.

Comment: Goran, thanks a lot! You right, it works.. I have yet another issue, but is separate one.. I thinks you've seen the one :)

Comment: hi Goran, if you have time, please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666423/iis-7-5-with-process-idenity-set-to-user-has-wrong-userprofile