# How to call Git from ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, windows, git, powershell

For my company, I created a software build system which is based on a bunch of Powershell scripts and an ASP.net web interface.

This build system is run every night by a scheduled task, but can also be run through the web interface. Source code are currently hosted by our CVS server and everything works.

Now, we are working on moving our source code to an external GIT hosting service. I made some changes into the Powershell scripts and the web interface, the goal is this SCM switch must not change the way people use the build system. And I created the SSH keys with no passphrase as recommended to run with an automatic scripting.

It works almost and that's the problem. If I run my build script manually, or through the overnight scheduled task, no trouble. But if I run it through the web interface, it doesn't work.

I checked twice the ASP.net web server is well run with impersonation to use the needed user account. But no way, the script stays blocked on the GIT process which never ends. I think there is some security or authentication issue in there, but I always fails to catch the GIT output.

The repository folder is well created, and there is a ".git" folder, but nothing more. The only output I catch is "Cloning ...".

I tried to run some posh-git utilities to start the ssh server, with no luck, this doesn't fix the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE: I've been able to catch some traces, here they are:

- Cloning into 'metamodels.fake'...
- fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666423/iis-7-5-with-process-idenity-set-to-user-has-wrong-userprofile). An environment variable HOME should be added to the system and point to the right user account.